# WDK: "named mounts" instead of drive letters - WinIFS

Tags: c, windows, filesystems, kernel, wdk

File-systems on Windows.

So, I have written my own FSD, and it gets assigned a drive letter, and if I reply appropriately to `IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_SUGGESTED_LINK_NAME` I can even change/set which drive letter to assign, for example by returning a string like "\DosDevices\G:".

But I would also be able to use "named mounts", like that of "C:\directory". I can not return that above (return buffer size is only enough to hold drive letter name).

So I have been trying for a while to get named mounts to work, but there seems to be many parts to it.  For example, using `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_CREATE_POINT` from kernel, IoCreateSymbolicLink() which some examples seem to use. Or is it better to use `FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT` from userland with `SetVolumeMountPoint()` ?

- So, I think I should be able to managed to get a "drive" mounted as "C:\Some\Directory" without having a drive letter.
- Should I seek a kernel-space, or userland, approach to setting a "named mount" (or does it require both?)
- If my FSD is done right, should it show in "Disk Manager" or will only real physical disks show there. Is that desirable?
- Is a reparse-point connected to mounts at all?

I do not think the MS Samples "fastfat" allows for named mounts, or I would follow its example.

Comment: I would certainly expect such a device to show in disk manager.

Comment: A mount point is a reparse point, i.e. a path component at which the object manager restarts parsing. It should use the reparse tag `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT`. The mount-point manager should assign your device a GUID volume name, i.e. "Volume{...}", associated with its [unique ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560441). This can be used as the substitute name in the [`MountPointReparseBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552012). NTFS and ReFS support NT reparse points, but FAT filesystems do not.

Comment: Ah so they are connected, now I wish I had returned FILE_SUPPORTS_REPARSE_POINTS when I started looking at this 2 weeks ago.   I spent all day trying to get HLK to work, as I heard there was a tester in there. Hassle to do, but I can at least run ifstest.exe now, and it has not been hard to find tests that fail, so I have something to do for now.

Comment: All Windows mount points are reparse points, but usually they're Object-Manager SymbolicLink objects. For example volume GUID names, DOS drive letters, and other DOS device names are persisted in the registry under "HKLM\System\MountedDevices" and "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices". You mentioned [`IoCreateSymbolicLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549043), which creates a link in the object manager's "\Global??" object directory, e.g. for the "C:" drive, "\Global??\C:" may be reparsed as "\Device\HarddiskVolume2".

Comment: To connect this in one example, say you create a junction mount point "C:\Mount\Spam" that redirects to "\??\Volume{...}", which in turn is associated with "\Device\HarddiskVolume10". Accessing "C:\Mount\Spam\Dir\File.ext" has to be reparsed initially as "\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Mount\Spam\Dir\File.ext". Then when the NTFS filesystem reaches "Spam", it reads the junction reparse point, so parsing starts over with "\??\Volume{...}\Dir\File.ext", which is finally reparsed as "\Device\HarddiskVolume10\Dir\File.ext".

Comment: Ok, sounds like they work a bit like vnode_mountedon in Unix, except instead of being "mounted on" when you issue a mount, you need to prepare a mountpoint by making it to a reparse point, which like a symlink, "points" to another place to continue name lookup. I'll continue using ifstest to make my code more correct, I only just learned about DELETE_ON_CLOSE on directories, surprise! :)

Comment: The difference to a Unix symlink is that reparse points are centralized in the filesystem, so `FindFirstVolumeMountPointW` can easily enumerate all mountpoints on a volume. It opens the special index stream "$Extend\$Reparse:$R:$INDEX_ALLOCATION" and enumerates all reparse points via `NtQueryDirectoryFile`, `FileReparsePointInformation`. A volume mountpoint uses the tag `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT` with a substitute path that's a "Volume{GUID}" name.

Comment: I got one more surprise discovery, like on Unix, I would just create the directory (mkdir, or Explorer new folder) then make it a REPARSE point - and not having much luck with it. But if I do as the examples, and call CreateFile to both create the dir, and mark it REPARSE things started working better.  It seems to open my volume with NULL name (volume open?) then call dirlist. But if I reply in dirlist, I see my files, so I feel confident something is working finally. But why should volumeopen return error if FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE, that is confusing...

Comment: So much learned. It uses SET_REPARSEPOINT and expects the FS to store the struct, which is returned with GET, or TagAttrInformation. The tag is also returned in EASize in dirlists. In MJ_CREATE, as you descend dirs, you need to check if each dir is a reparsepoint, and if so, return STATUS_REPARSE, setting the AuxBuf to the stored struct, and Reserved field to 'chars left in Filename'.

Comment: Are you trying to support reparse points in your own filesystem, or do you just need to support mounting your volume in an NTFS volume? For the latter your device just needs a "Volume{GUID}" name. Register support for [mount manager IOCTLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561594) such as `IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_UNIQUE_ID IOCTL` and `IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME IOCTL` (non-persistent). The mount manager creates and persists a "Volume{GUID}" name that's associated with the unique ID of your device, and maps this to the non-persistent device name that you provide.

Comment: Yep, I have all of it working. Both to set reparse point in C: (ntfs) and to set it in my own FS (zfs). It surprised me I had to detect reparse points during lookup, and return STATUS_REPARSE "manually".

Comment: I assume for the second sentence you're talking about implementing support for reparse points in your own FS. Why does it surprise you that parsing the new path has to jump back to the top in the Object Manager?

Comment: It surprised me that the Object Manager limits the number of reparse attempts for an open to 64 (or 32 in older versions). It also surprised me that the reparse buffer is limited to 16KB, split between the display name and the substitute path. Since an NT path is up to 64KB, we can't directly symlink to very long NT paths. An 8KB path is still more than long enough, so in practice it's not an issue, but it's still an ugly wart in the design.

Comment: Surprised in that "clearly I've been spoiled". All handled in VFS layer in Unix before calling the FS, so my FS would never see a "mounted on" vnode. Similarly, I discovered that my FS has to send all the fsevents as well (the DirectoryChangeNotify). Something I was previously used to VFS handling :)